# CSV using windows line break as a delimiter

Tags: mysql, csv, asp-classic

I'm trying to build a .CSV file out of information in a database. Unfortunately I don't have access to do this right from a SQL query and the rest of the site uses Classic ASP.

The information in the database often contains line breaks. Users enter this information with a html `<textarea>` field on a website. Line breaks show up in the resulting web page when the information is pulled from the database. The long term goal is to use the .CSV created here to change information then upload the file to update the database. Because of that I'm looking for a way to preserve the line breaks, or maybe replace them with `<br/>` tags.

The problem I'm running into is that Excel is using whatever line break character as a row delimiter. Is it better to replace the break character with `<br/>`? If that's the case how do I find the character I'm replacing for my `Replace()`? Is there a way to escape these characters and avoid the `replace()`? I've already got each cell surrounded by double quotes to escape other quotes.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to replace the line break character with a `<br/>` that seems to work just as well when information is displayed on the site. I ended up using

```
writethis = Replace(myString, vbCrLf, "<br/>")
```

Which replaced the line break with a `<br/>` and stopped the row from ending prematurely.